# Why clinch your hands, and center them, in portraits?

Tags: portrait

What's this pose called? Let's not call it [crossing your palms](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/cross-someone-s-palm-with-silver)!

Anyways, in portraits, the subject usually never shows hands. Then why clasp your hands, then center them in the center of the portrait? What do the clinched hands connote or denote?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[Top — Zenith](https://www.templechambers.com/member/zenith-chan). [Middle — Natalie](https://www.templechambers.com/member/natalie-so). [Bottom — Wilson](https://www.templechambers.com/member/wilson-leung).

Comment: If you take a picture of someone sitting at a table you have to show the hands. Keeping the hands under the table is considered impolite in many cultures (what are you doing under the table?).

Comment: @xenoid - yeah, but I'm sure there must be a way to not have everyone just look… scared, or even pleading. This doesn't work for me. It's not even the amateur psychologist's 'defensive uncertainty' pose, it makes everyone look like they were *told* to do that, without them understanding why. Hands cupping is an uncertainty pose, combined with leaning forwards is 'engagement, but don't come too close'. Oddly mixed messages. [Not going to put this in an answer because I'm not a psychologist]

Comment: Any pose with still/empty hands is awkward (ask Angela Merkel). A trick if to make them look like they are doing something (writing...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Portrait with folded hands

There are many references in art with descriptive titles where this type of portrait is often called **Portrait with folded hands**.

| [image] | [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *Portrait of a forty year old woman with folded hands*, Frans Hals, 1638 | *Portrait of an Old Woman with Folded Hands*, Jacob Adriaensz Backer, 1640 | *Woman with Folded Hands*, Käthe Kollwitz, 1898 |
| *[wikiart.org](https://www.wikiart.org/en/frans-hals/portrait-of-a-forty-year-old-woman-with-folded-hands-1638)* | *[wikiwand](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Portrait_of_an_Old_Woman_with_Folded_Hands8)* | *[artmuseum.princeton.edu](https://artmuseum.princeton.edu/collections/objects/15593)* |

About the meaning, more than a subjective reason, there's a practical and protocol issue regarding the position of arms and hands on a table.

#### Hands behind the table

The person gives the feeling of hiding something. Protocol, in almost all countries at the table the hands must always be visible.

[image]

Showing hands and their cleanliness represents clean hands = clean work.

#### Hands on the table

Situation of rest: the work already done or the lack of interest in doing it.

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |

#### Elbows on the table

Interest, always ready for action, work and work together.

> Placing your elbows on the table can emphasize interest and concentration.

<sup>*Source [theetiquetteconsultant.com](https://theetiquetteconsultant.com/blog/elbowsonthetable)*</sup>

Comment: Danielillo, it is good to read you around ;)

Comment: Yes, I'm freeeeeeeeee! 